# How to find and replace using regular expression in Cygwin

Tags: regex, replace, cygwin

I am trying to find an 'r' followed by a consonant and delete it in a text file 1.txt. My code is as follows

```
cat 1.txt | grep s/.*r([^aeiou])/\1/g
```

I know that grep command is used with regular expressions in Cygwin, but I am unable to do this.

Comment: I think you wanted to use `sed`, not `grep`. Try `sed 's/.*r\([^aeiou]\)/\1/g'`

Comment: does not work with sed too

Comment: It would help if you add a sample text and the desired output after substitution.

Answer (score 0):

`grep` will only find the required regex pattern in the input file. If you want to edit the file by removing those occurrences, you are better off using `sed`.

If your file is called `ab`, try this:

```
sed -i .bkp 's/r[^aeiou]//g' ab
```

Comment: can you use regular expressions with sed? What is .bkp? Thanks

Comment: This command will create a backup file, called `ab.bkp`, of the original file `ab`. The `-i` option provides the extension that you'd like to give to the backup file.

Comment: `r[^aeiou]` is a regex. So, yes, `sed` allows regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 'r'? Remove the consonant? Remove the line? Please clarify "delete it".

I'd recommend replacing `[^aeiou]` with `[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]` in the event you have `.*r[A-Z0-9]` somewhere in the doc.

Here I've split this into three queries and you can bring whatever text back in that you like with the \1\2\3:

`sed 's/\(.*\)\(r\)\([^aeiou]\)/\1\2\3/g' 1.txt`

'r' removal using SED:`sed 's/\(.*\)\(r\)\([^aeiou]\)/\1\3/g' 1.txt`

.*r removal using SED:`sed 's/\(.*\)\(r\)\([^aeiou]\)/\3/g' 1.txt`

Consonant removal using SED:`sed 's/\(.*\)\(r\)\([^aeiou]\)/\1\2/g' 1.txt`

r[^aeiou] removal using SED:`sed 's/\(.*\)\(r\)\([^aeiou]\)/\1/g' 1.txt`

**Line removal**

using sed:`sed '/r[^aeiouAEIOU]/d' 1.txt`

or the following, in case you have lines with numbers or symbols:

`sed '/r[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]/d' 1.txt`

**Line removal using grep:** `cat 1.txt | grep r[aeiouAEIOU]`

or the following, in case you have lines with numbers or symbols:

`cat 1.txt | grep -v r[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]`

Answer (score 0):

You got the wrong tool, as `grep(1)` only filters lines of input to the output, you need `sed(1)`, to edit the place where `[rR][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]` happens to occur.

```
sed 's/[rR]\([bcdfghijklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]\)/\1/g'
```

will erase only the first `r` or `R`.  If you need to erase both, just do

```
sed 's/[rR][bcdfghijklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]//g'
```